# Checking data after normalization with methods

Tags: python, pandas

I need to check data after normalization. I mean i normalized data in dataset and i need to inspect normalized data. As example, for StandartScaler i used this check to see that their mean is now 0 and the standard deviation is 1:

```
for col in df_norm.columns:
    print(f'{col}: {np.mean(df_norm[col]):.4f}, {np.std(df_norm[col]):.4f}')
```

I'm stuck on what check should i write for data normalized by RobustScaler and MaxAbsScaler methods

Answer (score 0):

you could use `df_norm.mean()`, and `df_norm.std()` instead of those for loop, so it will return mean and standard deviation of every columns respectively